# Como criar uma lista selecionável dinâmica em um objeto na Unity?

Tags: c#, lista, unity3d, gui

Gostaria de criar uma lista que apareceria quando o usuário clicasse em um botão. A lista mostraria as informações contidas no banco de dados, e ao usuário selecionar qual a desejada, iria dar continuidade ao jogo de acordo com a opção selecionada. Alguém conseguiria me ajudar nisso? Não precisa ter nenhum tipo de imagem, gostaria de fazer uma lista bem simples mesmo, onde tivesse apenas 1 ou 2 colunas, sendo a primeira com o nome "Id" e a segunda com nome "Tema", o usuário seleciona a linha desejada e eu utilizo o id correspondente ao tema selecionado. Se possível, queria fazer isso em uma espécie de "pop-up" que após ter o tema selecionado, sumiria, voltando a aparecer novamente apenas se o botão fosse clicado de novo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu implementei um exemplo mínimo aqui que pode te dar algumas idéias:

[image: Exemplo mínimo]

A lista em si é feita com o `UI > Scroll View`, tem um tutorial bacana [aqui](https://ouzaniabdraouf.medium.com/in-unityhow-to-use-the-scroll-view-ui-element-in-unity-71492e051618).

Essa é a hierarquia da cena:

[image: Hierarquia]

Eu criei duas animações pro `Scroll View`, uma `In` e outra `Out`. Elas mexem somente com a altura do `Scroll View`, a partir do centro, mas dá pra fazer qualquer animação (alpha, cor, posição, etc). Então, criei um componente `Animator` dentro do `Scroll View`, que organiza essas animações assim:

[image: Animator]

O state `Open` não tem nada. O state `Closed` tem a animação `In` congelada no primeiro frame (speed = 0). O trigger `In` ativa a transição `Any State -> In`. O trigger `Out` ativa a transição `Open -> Out`.

Se você não tá acostumado com o `Animator`, tem vários tutoriais espalhados por aí. O que falta é só chamar esses triggers pelo script:

```
public void OpenMenu()
{
    scroll.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("In");
}

public void CloseMenu()
{
    scroll.GetComponent<Animator>().SetTrigger("Out");
}
```

Lembrando que isso é só a descrição de uma técnica, não a solução, tem que refinar bastante pra colocar em produção. Espero que ajude!

Comment: valeu pela resposta! o que eu queria, na verdade, é uma maneira de criar uma tabela que mostrasse os elementos contidos no banco de acordo com a busca do usuário, e quando o usuário selecionasse, a tabela "fechasse" e desse continuidade a aplicação, com o elemento selecionado pelo usuário.

Comment: Então, você pode usar essa técnica e popular a tabela com os itens do banco de dados no `OpenMenu`. Cria um prefab do seu item, e quando abrir a lista você usa o `Instantiate` pra criar vários itens dentro do `Content` do `Scroll View`, alterando os textos pros valores do DB.

Comment: beleza, vou tentar fazer desse jeito então, valeu!

Comment: Eae cara, beleza? to querendo fazer um outro negócio no projeto e gostaria de usar como base essa solução que me forneceu, eu sei que é pedir demais, mas tem como vc colocar o passo a passo de como fazer esse processo? queria fazer exatamente do jeito que fez na solução. Procurei uns vídeos de como usar o animator mas a maioria é ensinando a mexer em objetos que já estão aparentes na UI, não achei nenhum que ao clicar em um botão, o scrollview aparecesse na frente, igual vc fez

Answer (score 0):

A sua descrição bate parcialmente com a de uma combobox, recomendo que você veja o elemento "Dropdown" da UI do unity3D:

[Dropdown | Unity UI | 1.0.0](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/script-Dropdown.html)

Comment: cheguei a dar uma olhada no dropdown, mas a miunha intenção é ter no mínimo 10 opções pro usuário escolher. creio que fazer utilizando dropdown ficaria com uma "aparência" desagradavel e/ou bagunçada